# Bad Responsive Cordova app

Tags: android, cordova

I have a question relationed with Cordova.

This summer I have start to develop an Android App in cordova because i want to learn it. My app is made with w3 css.

I had started to made it and all was ok, but I must to format my laptop and i have to reinstall cordova, android SDK and JDK. When I was compile this app before format the PC looks like an app, and now no.

I'm trying to undo all new changes, but I dont find the solution.

Maybe some of you had this problems and you can help me. I will apport all info you need.

I undo all changes and I delete w3 css and I do my own css and this looks equal. I tried to decompile the old app and compile the source code again and looks bad too.

I put images (I know that is so ugly but are just tests)

[Before format (Cordova February 2016)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNjWI.png)

[After format (Cordova July 2017)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6pIk.png)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow. Please do not post your solution in the question, mark the answer of @Madpop as right or write your own answer.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did u add `<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">` ?

Comment: Yes I forgot this, and now it runs well THANKS